# How Bockstein homomorphism maps under Poincarè duality?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, poincare-duality

Given a manifold $X$ and short exact sequence of abelian groups
$$
1\rightarrow A_1\overset{\iota}{\rightarrow} A_2\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} A_3\rightarrow 1
$$
we get the Bockstein map in cohomology $\beta : H^p(X,A_3)\rightarrow H^{p+1}(X,A_1)$. On cochains this is defined as follows. Choose a section $s:A_3\rightarrow A_2$, then given $f\in Z^p(X,A_3)$, $s(f)\in C^{p}(X,A_2)$ is not closed, but $\pi(\delta (s(f)))=0$ and thus there exists $\beta(f)\in Z^{p+1}(X,A_1)$ such that $\iota(\beta(f))=\delta s(f)$. In a similar way one can define the Bockstein map in homology $b : H_k(X,A_3)\rightarrow H_{k-1}(X,A_1)$. On a chain $c\in Z_k(X,A_3)$ this is defined such that $\iota(b(c))=\partial s(c)$. In the last equation for any map $m : A\rightarrow B$ (even not a homomorphism) of abelian groups and $c\in C_k(X,A)$ I denoted by $m(c)\in C_k(X,B)$ the chains obtained by acting with $m$ on the coefficients.

On the other hand, if $X$ is orientable, by using Poincarè duality $\Phi_A :H_p(X,A)\rightarrow H^{d-p}(X,A)$ for homology/cohomology we induce a map in homology $b': H_p(X,A_3)\rightarrow H_{p-1}(X,A_1)$ as follows. Given $c\in H_p(X,A_3)$, construct $\Phi _{A_3}(c)\in H^{d-p}(X,A_3)$, and then by using the Bockstein $\beta(\Phi_{A_3}(c))\in H^{d-p+1}(X,A_1)$. Then define
$$
b'(c)=\Phi_{A_1}^{-1}\left(\beta(\Phi_{A_3}(c))\right)
$$

It is natural to expect that $b'=b$ but this does not seem to me totally obvious. I tried to prove it but at some point I need to use $\Phi$ on non-closed cycles (which I don't know how much is legal) and I would need to prove that this action commutes with the section $s:A_3\rightarrow A_1$, and I don't know how to do this...

Comment: Your section has to go to $A_2$.

Comment: Don't use $\Phi$: check that the two Bocksteins are the dual of each other under the Kronecker pairing between homology and cohomology. The advantage is that the pairing is defined on the whole complex.

Comment: I think this is a totally different question, for instance the Kronecker pairing does not induce an isomorphism in general because of torsion. However it is also a very interesting question and I would be very interested in knowing how Bockstein maps across Kronecker pairing... could you provide the details?